has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check in laravel
I am adding Stripe payment gateway to Laravel project and Aden I start requesting subscription to package using test mode and I get the following error
Can you please tell me why and how to fix it
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
This is the code function that I am implementing
code
   public function subscriptions_checkout(Request $request, string $plan)
   {

   return $request->user()
   ->newSubscription('default', $plan)
   ->checkout([
   'success_url' => route('success_checkout'),
   'cancel_url' => route('plans'),
   ]);
   }

end code

Are you by any chance using Laravel with Inertia.js?

CORS error responses can often be a result of a completely different issue. For example, if the API you're trying to reach is not responding at all, the preflight request doesn't receive a response and the browser reports the pre-flight check failed. Have you confirmed that your endpoint is responding correctly (attempt to reach it using Postman)?

You should Check your Cors.php in config.
There you should add localhost:3000 if u are running local.
 'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

CORS are built-in in your browser so it might be a client sided thing.
If the error still continues try adding CORS extension in your browser for development purposes.
This should be good enough to get you go during development.
